# Why won't gsub! change my files?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to do a simple find/replace on all text files in a directory, modifying any instance of `[RAVEN_START:` by inserting a string (in this case 'raven was here') before the line.

Here is the entire ruby program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'fileutils' #for FileUtils.mv('your file', 'new location')

class RavenParser

  rawDir = Dir.glob("*.txt")
  count = 0
  rawDir.each do |ravFile|
    #we have selected every text file, so now we have to search through the file
    #and make the needed changes.
    rav = File.open(ravFile, "r+") do |modRav|
      #Now we've opened the file, and we need to do the operations.
        if modRav            
        lines = File.open(modRav).readlines
        lines.each { |line|
        if line.match /\[RAVEN_START:.*\]/ 
          line.gsub!(/\[RAVEN_START:/, 'raven was here '+line)
          count = count + 1
        end
        }
         printf("Total Changed: %d\n",count)
      else
         printf("No txt files found. \n")
      end
    end
    #end of file replacing instructions.
  end

  # S
end
```

The program runs and compiles fine, but when I open up the text file, there has been no change to any of the text within the file. `count` increments properly (that is, it is equal to the number of instances of `[RAVEN_START:` across all the files), but the actual substitution is failing to take place (or at least not saving the changes).

Is my syntax on the `gsub!` incorrect? Am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're reading the data, updating it, and then neglecting to write it back to the file. You need something like:

```
# And save the modified lines.
File.open(modRav, 'w') { |f| f.puts lines.join("\n") }
```

immediately before or after this:

```
printf("Total Changed: %d\n",count)
```

As [DMG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14253/dgm) notes below, just overwriting the file isn't properly paranoid as you could be interrupted in the middle of the write and lose data. If you want to be paranoid (which all of us should be because *they* really are out to get us), then you want to write to a [temporary file](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/classes/Tempfile.html) and then do an atomic rename to replace the original file the new one. A rename generally only works when you stay within a single file system as there is no guarantee that the OS's temp directory (which `Tempfile` uses by default) will be on the same file system as `modRav` so [`File.rename`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M000019) might not even be an option with a `Tempfile` unless precautions are taken. But the `Tempfile` constructor takes a `tmpdir` parameter so we're saved:

```
modRavDir = File.dirname(File.realpath(modRav))
tmp       = Tempfile.new(modRav, modRavDir)
tmp.write(lines.join("\n"))
tmp.close
File.rename(tmp.path, modRav)
```

You might want to stick that in a separate method (`safe_save(modRav, lines)` perhaps) to avoid further cluttering your block.

Comment: Of course, if the program interrupts in the right place, you might end up losing data this way... it's better to output to a temp file first, and then move the file back to the original name.  See: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/classes/Tempfile.html and http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_ruby/fileaccess.html

Comment: @DGM: True enough, a temp file followed by an atomic rename would be proper paranoia. However, a rename on Tempfile may not be atomic as the temp file might be on another file system so it might end up as a file-copy rather than a simple `rename` system call. So you'd need to set the `tmpdir` to match `modRav` when building your Tempfile. I'll add an update about that for completeness.

Comment: exactly right.  I knew that knowledge was out there, but I wasn't coming up with any better links on little sleep.  But this little routine **should** be common knowledge in the programming world.  It needs more exposure if not. :)

Comment: @DGM: So I've been tricked into working around your lack of sleep? Fair enough :)

Comment: I know I've already accepted the answer, but I have one more question: what would I have to add to the above code in order to make a backup of the original? So I would have, for example, both data.txt (the modified file) and data.txt.bk (the original file, renamed).

Comment: @Raven: `File.rename(x, x + '.bk')` to move the original to a backup file, then skip the temp-file stuff and use a simple `File.open` to write out the new stuff.

Comment: @mu - hm. Trying to rename the file is giving me an access error. Also, I can't believe I didn't see that; it was clearly the last line of your answer.

Comment: @Raven: Do you have a permissions problem?

Comment: @mu - I think I do. I'll take that to its own question, though.

Answer (score 5):

1. There is no `gsub!` in the post (except the title and question). I would actually recommend *not* using `gsub!`, but rather use the result of `gsub` -- avoiding mutability can help reduce a number of subtle bugs.
2. The line *read* from the file stream *into* a String is a *copy* and modifying it will not affect the contents of the file. (The general approach is to read a line, process the line, and write the line. Or do it all at once: read all lines, process all lines, write all processed lines. In either case, nothing is being written back to the file in the code in the post ;-)

Happy coding.

Comment: Re @2. - How would I go about fixing it so that I *am* writing back to the file?

Comment: @Raven Dreamer `File.open` returns an object of [`class IO`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html). One approach is to read all lines (as is done), *truncate* the IO (clear all the data, keeps the file open), and then as each line is processed, write the processed back -- in this case a simple `gsub` is fine as the result is passed to `write` and not stored otherwise :) Make sure the file is opened in the correct mode and append the appropriate line terminator.

Comment: Oops, I forget Ruby doesn't have `IO.truncate`. In this case, close the file (opened for reading to get the lines), and re-open the file for writing -- "w" flag -- do not specify for append.

Comment: I opened the file in R+ mode, which should include write access already.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer The point of re-opening in "w" is to *truncate* the file (e.g. what happens if less characters are to be written? It is for this reason a simple seek won't suffice.). However, see the comment by DGM in mu is too short's answer, which brings up a valid consideration.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using `gsub!`, you're using `gsub`. `gsub!` and `gsub` different methods, one does replacement on the object itself and the other does replacement then returns the result, respectively.

Change this

`line.gsub(/\[RAVEN_START:/, 'raven was here '+line)`

to this :

`line.gsub!(/\[RAVEN_START:/, 'raven was here '+line)`

or this:

`line = line.gsub(/\[RAVEN_START:/, 'raven was here '+line)`

See [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001186) for more info

Comment: I've updated the original post. I *was* using gsub!. Foolish copy + paste error on my part.